# Tensorboard Callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks 
import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

early_stopping =EarlyStopping(patience=5, monitor='val_loss', mode='min')
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(patience=4,monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1)

#path for saving the best weights
checkpoint_best_path =r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktop\Work\Data Science\Practice\Machine Learning\Deep Learning\Custom Deep Learning\Deep Learning with Computer vision\Basics\Covid 19 Project\Model\Model best checkpoint'

check_bestpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_best_path, save_weights_only=True, save_freq='epoch',
                                 monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, verbose=1)


#tensorboard path
log_dir_path =r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktop\Work\Data Science\Practice\Machine Learning\Deep Learning\Custom Deep Learning\Deep Learning with Computer vision\Basics\Covid 19 Project\Data\logs/' 
log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir_path, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,histogram_freq=1)

callbacks= [early_stopping, learning_rate_reduction,check_bestpoint,tensorboard_callback]
```

but I got an error stating :

> NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:
> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktop\Work\Data
> Science\Practice\Machine Learning\Deep Learning\Custom Deep
> Learning\Deep Learning with Computer vision\Basics\Covid 19
> Project\Data\logs/20220628-231734\train/events.out.tfevents.1656501454.DESKTOP-1ULGF16.14344.2.v2
> : The system cannot find the path specified. ; No such process
> Creating writable file
> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktop\Work\Data
> Science\Practice\Machine Learning\Deep Learning\Custom Deep
> Learning\Deep Learning with Computer vision\Basics\Covid 19
> Project\Data\logs/20220628-231734\train/events.out.tfevents.1656501454.DESKTOP-1ULGF16.14344.2.v2
> Could not initialize events writer. [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]

Answer (score 0):

Check that folder you are trying to save the weights to exists.

If it doesnt exist you can create it using pathlib such as

```
from pathlib import Path

#tensorboard path 
log_dir_path =r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Desktop\Work\Data Science\Practice\Machine Learning\Deep Learning\Custom Deep Learning\Deep Learning with Computer vision\Basics\Covid 19 Project\Data\logs/'
log_dir = os.path.join(log_dir_path, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))

Path.mkdir(Path(log_dir), exist_ok=True, parents=True)

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir,histogram_freq=1)
```

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: Try removing the the / from the end of log_dir_path